# Background image on div not being responsive

Tags: php, html, css, image

[Here you can see a white gap when I scroll right](http://gyazo.com/506eded18a0293c875f0b8d96501483b) I want that gap to be deleted, here's my code:

```
<div class="top fullscreen background parallax img-responsive" id="inicio" style="background-image:url('images/fondos/<? echo rand(1,5); ?>.png');" " data-img-width="1920" data-img-height="1080" data-diff="250">
    <div class="content-a">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="content-b">
            <div class="dark-line">
                <h1>Bedif</h1>
                <!-- <img src="images/bedif636x144.png" class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 offset-md-6" style="margin-left: auto;  margin-right: auto;"> -->
                    <? if($this->session->flashdata('error')){?>
                            <p><div class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 500px;margin-left: auto;  margin-right: auto;"><? echo $this->session->flashdata('error') ?></div></p>
                    <?}?>
                <p>

                <?php echo form_open("login/entrar",'class="form-inline"'); ?>                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Iniciar sesion</button>
                </form>
                </p>
                <p>Para registrar una cuenta, entra en <b>Bedif</b> usando la ip <b>mc.bedif.net</b></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: repeating background? or strech or ?

Comment: We need to see the CSS to be able to help. Can you post it?

Comment: are you referring to the white gap on the scroll bar ?

Comment: The way you are centering your `div#navbar` is causing it to expand too far to the right. I normally don't suggest using `!important`, but a quick (not necessarily good) fix is to add `!important` to `overflow:hidden` in the definition in styles.css on line 362. Bootstrap is overriding your style with `overflow:visible !important`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Try this

```
body{
 overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

This should work let me know

**SideNote**

In your html you have a minor error in your inline style, I highlighted it below

```
<div class="top fullscreen background parallax img-responsive not-overflow" id="inicio" style="background-image: url(&quot;images/fondos/3.png&quot;); background-attachment: fixed; background-size: 1991.11px 1120px; background-position: 50% -125px;" "="" data-img-width="1920" data-img-height="1080" data-diff="250">
```

if you look after -125px;" you have "=""

Comment: wait this image is not assigned as a background if I'm looking at your code correctly?

Comment: its assigned as the div background (the php randomly picks an image)

Comment: I may be blind but I do not see a white gap, please to a print screen and highlight what you're seeing

Comment: without scrolling right (default view) http://gyazo.com/cb4d07c2018a036c98b31e2408024534

Comment: from the link you provided the white block is a part of the image. I opened it up in Photoshop. You can do one of two things I'll update my response

Comment: As you can see here, the image hasn't got any kind of white block.... http://gyazo.com/0b756678365ceef5b8765a834371b9ec

Comment: @CarlosXam-mar sorry I took so long I'm at work, I've updated the answer and I'm positive this should work let me know.

Comment: Check out the website now, the bug is solved, but now the menus don't follow your scroll ¿any idea?

Comment: It's scrolling to me on both firefox and chrome

Comment: But now the image keeps "bugged"